# How to use start.exe and cmd.exe with Run command in autohotkey v2?

Tags: windows, cmd, autohotkey

I am new to autohotkey. I am trying to run a script in a separate command prompt window. For now I am not able to run a simple `dir` command:

```
^+å::
{
    Run 'start "' A_ComSpec '" /k dir'
}
```

Note that the command `start C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe "/k dir"` runs fine from the powershell prompt, but when launched by autohotkey, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Remove the word `start`: `Run(A_ComSpec " /k dir")`

Comment: @0x464e Yes that worked! But why does the "start" work in powershell? If I don't use "start" in powershell, the "dir" command is run in the current terminal window.

Comment: AHK's `run` run's a program. [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) is a command not a program.

Comment: @0x464e Ahh, I think I got it. "start" is an internal command built into cmd: https://superuser.com/a/1178485/278134, so it cannot be run by an external program like "AHK", it is only recognized by the CMD.exe and Powershell.exe commands. Thanks for clarifying!